# How to get meson to use a library in a different lib directory?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, linker

I have two versions of a library, zita-convolver3 and zita-convolver4. The system library is zita-convolver3, but i want to link against zita-convolver4, which is stored in a local user directory.

How do i get meson to compiler.find_library zita-convolver4 instead of prioritising the system version zita-convolver3? I can work around this by using a pkg-config file and setting the pkgconfig_path to explicitly set this. But is there a way of doing it using only meson?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I could do this by writing a separate pkg-config file. But IIRC, for this particular project, the pkg-config settings weren't being used and I had to explicitly specify the -L directory as part of the link arguments.